# Is higher or lower specific heat better for cooling an object via contact?

Tags: mathematical-physics, thermal-conductivity

Suppose you want to cool an object by putting it into contact with another object, much colder object, and the transferal of joules to an intermediary equilibrium temperature is instantaneous.

If this is your preferred method of cooling, then is it theoretically more plausible to use a high specific-heat substance or a lower specific heat substance to cool your object?

Even though this might seem like a simple application of the specific heat problem $Q = mcT,$ a bigger "$c$" gives you more joules of energy to average between, but it gives you a bigger divisor in the denominator when calculating the final temperature. So which is better? A higher or lower specific heat?

If the answer is "doesn't matter", then is there a material-specific property that does matter in determining why some materials make better coolants than others?

Comment: How much cooling do want to do?  What is the mass of each object?  Also note that in the real world, the thermal conductivity of each object would affect how long it would take to achieve the cooling.

Comment: @DavidWhite Yes but the question appears to be specifically about steady state (equilibrium), not about rate of cooling (the transient).

Comment: @Gert, my point is that it is not physically possible to instantly transfer heat in order to achieve that equilibrium temperature.

Comment: @DavidWhite Yes, that first paragraph of the question is indeed rather awkward, to say the least! Instantaneous transfer of heat is of course completely imposssible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adiabatic$^\dagger$ heat balance during the heat transfer for objects $1$ (hot) and $2$ (cold) is:

$$m_1c_1(T_1-T_0)+m_2c_2(T_2-T_0)=m_1c_1(T_f-T_0)+m_2c_2(T_f-T_0)$$

where $T_0$ is a reference temperature, which drops out to give:

$$m_1c_1T_1+m_2c_2T_2=m_1c_1T_f+m_2c_2T_f$$

Thus the final temperature $T_f$ becomes:

$$T_f=\frac{m_1c_1T_1+m_2c_2T_2}{m_1c_1+m_2c_2}$$

So the influence of $c_2$ is not straightforward because it appears *in both the numerator and the denominator.*

This apparent ambiguity arises from the fact that *the masses have to be taken into account too*. Just imagine if the hotter object would be much larger than the colder one: $m_1 \gg m_2$. In that case the final temperature tends toward $T_1$, regardless of $c_2$.

$^\dagger$ No heat loss to the environment, only 'internal' heat exchange between the objects..

Comment: This is close to what I derived, thank you. However, there is a derivation you can make if you plot varying $c_1$ at fixed temperatures and masses, which is that the specific heat doesn't appear to cause that much of a change within known ranges. Instead, the largest determining factors are masses and temperatures.

Comment: @StackQuest Yes, fully agreed.

Answer (score -1):

You could look at the question intuitively and get your answer without algebra. You know that increasing heat capacity increases the amount of heat a cold objects needs to take in order to raise its temperature. So imagine that you need 10,000 J to bring your hot object from 500 K to 400 K. Let's say that's the same amount of energy you need to heat a cold object up to 400 K from 300 K. Now say you INCREASE the heat capacity of your cold object. That means that your cold object now needs MORE than 10,000 J to go from 300 K to 400 K. Translation, once your hot object cools from 500 K to 400 K, your cold object is STILL COLDER THAN 400K. That means that the cold object can absorb MORE heat from your hot object, leading to a LOWER equilibrium temperature.